# Group by and Sum in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I have a table which has two columns , say for example the table name is demo and columns are id and percentage

```
    id      percentage
     1          50
     2          74
     1          66
```

Now I would like to group by id and then take sum of the percentage and then select records based on some condition say sum of percentage less than 40.

I have the following sql query, which gives me correct results.

```
SELECT id ,(SELECT SUM("demo"."percentage")
AS sum_allocation_percentage FROM "demo" GROUP BY id)as 
sum_allocation_percentage from demo where sum_allocation_percentage < 100;
```

I need this query to be in rails 3.

Demo.group('id').sum(:percentage)

How should I proceed after this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can used `having` clause as

```
Demo.group('id').having("sum(percentage) < 100")
```

Comment: Demo.select("id").group('id').having("sum(percentage) < 100")